# Javascript Date Time Validation - yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Tags: javascript, validation, datetime

I want to create a very simple javascript form validation. I have two input boxes that are populated by a datetime picker. the datetime picker populates the input box with in the format 2011-12-21 09:58. I have an input box for collection date and arrival date.

I want to validate that the 'deliverdatetime' entered is greater than the 'collectdatetime'.

The output of a failed validation should just be in a popup window saying 'deliverdate' before 'coolectdate'.

Can this be done with javascript and if so can someone give me a brief example?

my basic html form code is:

```
...
<td>
<input type="text" id="collectdatetime" name="collectdatetime">
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="deliverdatetime" name="deliverdatetime" >
</td>
...
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance and happy holidays to everyone.

Regards,
Ryan Smith

Comment: Given the format, you can just compare them as strings, there is no need to convert them to date objects.

Comment: Hi @Rob, can you provide a sample code at all as my javascript knowledge is shocking. Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIven the ISO8601 format of the date/time string, you can just compare the values as strings. It's one of the beauties of using an ISO8601 format. You have asked for the delivery time to be after the collection time, which seems backwards to me but anyhow…

```
<form onsubmit="return checkDates(this)">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="collectdatetime" name="collectdatetime">
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="deliverdatetime" name="deliverdatetime">
      <td>
        <input type="submit">
  </table>
</form>

<script>
function checkDates(form) {
  if (form.collectdatetime.value >= form.deliverdatetime.value) {
    alert('Collection time must be after deliver time');
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Rob, Thanks for this, works perfectly as per your example. I am battling to encorporate this into my page however. After the </form> I have another script [found here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) performing validation on the other fields. when I add your script, the existing validation script works but your datetime validation is ignored. any suggestions, I'll add the complete page script hereafter, thanks for the help. Ryan

Comment: my form tag..... <form onsubmit="return checkDates(this)" name="myform" id="myform" action=captureshuttledelivery2.php method=post>

Comment: code after </form>....

<script> 
function checkDates(form) { 
  if (form.collectdatetime.value >= form.deliverdatetime.value) { 
    alert('Collection time must be after deliver time'); 
    return false; 
  } 
} 
</script> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve">
//<![CDATA[ 
   var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("trailer","dontselect=0","Please select a TRAILER TYPE");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("source","dontselect=0","Please select a SOURCE");
//]]>
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var collectTime = (new Date(document.getElementById("collectdatetime").value)).getTime(),
    deliverTime = (new Date(document.getElementById("deliverdatetime").value)).getTime();
if(deliverTime > collectTime) {
    //Ok!
}
```

This creates 2 `Date` objects, passing the selected values to the constructor, and then compares the times. The [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method returns a number representing the time that has passed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 in milliseconds.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hHE8D/).

Comment: Thanks @James, Where do I place this in my code so that the validation is executed when I click the submit button? Thanks, Ryan

Comment: You would need to bind a `submit` event handler to the form (or a `click` event to the button). In the event handler you can run your validation.

Comment: Thanks James, can you assist with the complete script? Apologies but I do not know any Java Script. I presume we need an onClick="showAlert();" for the submit button, but how do I call that exact script? Thanks again, R

Comment: Google will probably be the best place to go. Search for "JavaScript event handlers" or something like that and start reading about it. If you run into specific problems, post a question on here and people will be happy to help. That way, you're more likely to learn it and remember it for next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Date object from this values and compare them:

```js
var collect = new Date($('#collectdatetime').val());
var delivery = new Date($('#deliverdatetime').val());

if (delivery < collect) {
    alert('Delivery date before collect!');
}
```

Comment: note that this only works because `<` triggers an automatic call to each Date's `.valueOf()` method.

Comment: Also note that there is no mention whatsoever of jQuery in the question, so it's unlikely the OP is looking for a solution that involves it.