# javascript form validation - call two scripts on form submit

Tags: javascript, validation, scripting, submit

I have a php as shown below. the page has some javascript validation. I am making use of gen_validatorv4.js found on site [found here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml#download).

This script works perfectly however cannot do a comparison validation on date time fields. To do this I got help from another stackoverflow post [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586646/javascript-date-time-validation-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm/8595352#8595352). Thanks to @RobG who gave me a working datetime comparison validation script.

my issues is that when I add both scripts to the page only one works, disabling the other. How can I get both sets of code to be called when submitting the form?

My complete code ii found below, thanks for the help in advance and holiday wishes to everyone!
Ryan

```
<html>
<head>
<title>

</title>
<script src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="gen_validatorv4.js" type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve"></script>
</head>


<body>

<?PHP
$usernname1=$session->username;

//trailers
$trailers="SELECT vehicletypename from vehicletypes"; 
$resulttrailer=mysql_query($trailers); 

$optionstrailer=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resulttrailer)) { 

    $trailer=$row["vehicletypename"]; 
    $optionsdelivery.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$trailer\">".$trailer; 
} 



//Source
$sources="SELECT sourcename from shuttlesources"; 
$resultsources=mysql_query($sources); 

$optionssources=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultsources)) { 

    $sourcename=$row["sourcename"]; 
    $optionssources.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$sourcename\">".$sourcename; 
} 


//Destination
$destination="SELECT destinationname from shuttledestinations"; 
$resultdestination=mysql_query($destination); 

$optionsdestination=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultdestination)) { 

    $destinationname=$row["destinationname"]; 
    $optionsdestination.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$destinationname\">".$destinationname; 
} 


//routes
$routesql="SELECT routename from deliveryroutes where transporttype='localpmb'"; 
$resultdestination=mysql_query($routesql); 

$optionsroute=""; 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultdestination)) { 

    $routename=$row["routename"]; 
    $optionsroute.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$routename\">".$routename; 
} 

?>



<form onsubmit="return checkDates(this)" name="myform" id="myform" action=captureshuttledelivery2.php method=post>
<font color=red><b>Provide information to create shuttle delivery</b></font><br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>TRAILER
</td>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>SOURCE
</td>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>WEIGHT
</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>
    <SELECT NAME=trailer style="width:140px;"> 
    <OPTION VALUE=0>
    <?=$optionsdelivery?> 
    </SELECT> 
</td>
<td>
    <SELECT NAME=source style="width:140px;"> 
    <OPTION VALUE=0>
    <?=$optionssources?> 
    </SELECT> 
</td>
<td>
<input type=text name=weight id=weight>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>REF NUMBER 1</b></font>
</td>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>REF NUMBER 2</b></font>
</td>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>REF NUMBER 3</b></font>
</td>
<td width=150>
<font color=blue>REF NUMBER 4</b></font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type=text name=refnumber id=refnumber>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text name=refnumber2 id=refnumber2>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text name=refnumber3 id=refnumber3>
</td>
<td>
<input type=text name=refnumber4 id=refnumber4>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<font color=blue>COLLECTION TIME
</td>
<td>
<font color=blue>DELIVERY TIME
</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>
<input type="text" id="collectdatetime" name="collectdatetime">
 <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('collectdatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="deliverdatetime" name="deliverdatetime" >
 <img src="images2/cal.gif" onclick="javascript:NewCssCal ('deliverdatetime','yyyyMMdd','dropdown',true,'24')"  style="cursor:pointer"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan=4>
<font color=blue>COMMENTS
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=4>
<input type=text name=comments id=comments size=100 value=none>
</td>
</tr>


</table>
<table>
<tr><td>
<input type=submit name=submit id=submit value="Save Delivery">
</td></tr></table>


</form>

<script> 
function checkDates(form) { 
  if (form.collectdatetime.value >= form.deliverdatetime.value) { 
    alert('Collection time must be after deliver time'); 
    return false; 
  } 
} 
</script> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" xml:space="preserve">
//<![CDATA[
//You should create the validator only after the definition of the HTML form
  var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("trailer","dontselect=0","Please select a TRAILER TYPE");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("source","dontselect=0","Please select a SOURCE");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("weight","req","Please enter the LOAD WEIGHT");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("weight","numeric","Entered LOAD WEIGHT not a number");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("refnumber","req","Please enter at least one REFERENCE NUMBER");
  frmvalidator.addValidation("refnumber","numeric");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("collectdatetime","req","Please enter a COLLECTION DATE AND TIME");

  frmvalidator.addValidation("deliverdatetime","req","Please enter a DELIVERY DATE AND TIME");

//]]>

</script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Why the hell do you post this as comment? It's definitive not a comment to the question, it's an answer! This makes absolutely no sense since Ryan Smith can't mark this as the correct answer. Please enlighten with an explanation of the purpose!

Comment: @mplungjan I think it's a good answer but I don't think it's a good comment so, no. I'll wait for a similar answer. I admit it is just as a matter of principle but I don't like these answering comments everywhere in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Okeee.......... - removed the comments and posted as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need a [CUSTOM](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml#custom) validator since the two values cannot be directly compared

this is not tested - I would think we would need to create dates or access the datpicker getTime() values instead of string values from the input field:

```
frmvalidator.setAddnlValidationFunction("DoCustomValidation");

function DoCustomValidation() {
  var form = document.forms["myform"];
  if (form.collectdatetime.value >= form.deliverdatetime.value) { 
    alert('Collection time must be after deliver time'); 
    return false; 
  } 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Now my worlds balance is restored :)